# How to move file to a new folder after renaming with datetime in the previous folder

Tags: c#

I have the following code which grabs the most recent file based on the file creation date:
Then I rename the file with the current date and time at the end.

I need to move the file to a new folder after renaming it.

Note: this is where I am at: I tried using `File.Move` again or `File.MoveTo` but it's not happening.

```
string currentdir = @"X:\ActiveDirectory\";
string filePattern = "datafile*";

string newName = "newfile_" + 
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy.HH.mm.ss") + ".csv";

DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(currentdir);
var file = info.GetFiles(filePattern).
OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime).First();
File.Move(file.FullName, file.FullName.ToString()
.Replace(file.ToString(), newName));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the old file's fullname for the destination, try this:

```
string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDir, newName)
System.IO.File.Move(file.FullName, newPath);
```

Comment: I keep getting this error, even before posting saying `Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`

Comment: Okay I modified a bit: Changed the `currentDir` to the new directory. Created a new directory and used it as an argument.
`string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(newDirectory, newName)
System.IO.File.Move(file.FullName, newPath);`